# Model comparison between inherently different machine-learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-selection, model-evaluation, model-comparison

For example, how to fairly compare the performance of **XGBoost**/**LightGBM** to the performance of a **Feed-Forward Neural Network**? Especially regarding (1) **Data Preprocessing** and (2) **Hyperparameter Tuning**? Both steps can differ greatly for the mentioned algorithms - so how to make sure the results aren't biased due to suboptimal data processing?

I know that there won't be the one correct answer to this question since the problem is non-trivial.

However, are there any *best practices* that could mitigate the risk to obtain biased results in said model comparison? Does anyone know of research papers that approach this issue in a reasonable way? Are there libraries that try to approach hyperparameter tuning objectively for all sorts of machine-learning models [...]?

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the concrete circumstances as you suggest yourself. However, there are some good pracitces you can follow.

Firstly, part of the data preprocessing is conditional on the algorithm you use. If you use a regression you might want to encode categorical variables for example. Therefore, you could have two different preprocessed datasets for two different algorithms.

Secondly, hyper-parameter tuning is also, of course, algo specific. The possible grid of hyperparameters differ significantly between different algos. Thus, you would have different grids.

Lastly, you almost always perform algorithms in terms of their performance. If you feed the same data (note that encoding categorical variables for a regression as discussed above does not change the nature of the data, just the format, hence it is still the same input) to the algorithm you can compare the cross-validated performance and based on that you can tell which algorithm performs better.

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: Yes, I fear the answer is simply to preprocess and tune individually until an [achievable] optimum. With that, unfortunately, such comparisons will always be biased in a way. Nevertheless, there might be some papers comparing different models and potentially AutoML frameworks that reduce human interaction. Although even these frameworks will most likely be optimised for a certain kind of algorithm. Maybe there also exists some kind of permutation approach to get an average performance for different parameters/feature sets [...]. Nonetheless, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well you could do it "objectively" by having, per algo, a complete grid that looks at each possible hyperparameter for this algo and includes many possible values (if full search) or broad ranges (random search, bayesian). However, as I pointed out this would always be algorithm specific. As would be particular aspects of the preprocessing. I beleive this addresses the question. You can mark the answer as a solution if you agree with that notion.